# Absolutely positioning elements in 4.01 strict on FF

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a simple tooltip custom tag in ColdFusion that has worked great in IE quirks mode.  But now we're moving towards cross-browser support and the placement script is not working correctly when Firefox is put into strict mode.  The code is designed to place the tooltip immediately below the element that the user is hovering over, but in strict mode the tooltip is instead appearing about 12-13 pixels too high.

Could someone please tell me why this is occuring?  Is the 'top' being reported incorrectly for the hover element, or is absolute positioning working incorrectly for the tooltip element?

Below is some simplified test code that shows the problem; remove the 'DOCTYPE' tag to make it work correctly.  Note that this works correctly on IE8 in both quirks mode and standards mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/css/standard.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/css/standard_projector.css" media="projection">
        <title>OTIS Shell</title>
        <script>
                var stillOver = 0;

                function tipShowHide(tipID, deed) {
                    for (i=1; i<=numTips; i++) {
                        if (i != stillOver) {
                            document.getElementById('ToolTip' + i).style.visibility         = 'hidden';
                            document.getElementById('ToolTip' + i).style.display            = 'none';
                        }
                    }
                    if (stillOver == tipID) {
                        if (deed == 1) {
                            tipTop = getRealTop(document.getElementById('ToolTipParent' + tipID)) + document.getElementById('ToolTipParent' + tipID).offsetHeight;
                            tipLeft = getRealLeft(document.getElementById('ToolTipParent' + tipID));

                            tipTop = getRealTop(document.getElementById('ToolTipParent' + tipID)) + document.getElementById('ToolTipParent' + tipID).offsetHeight;

                            document.getElementById('ToolTip' + tipID).style.top        = tipTop + 'px';
                            document.getElementById('ToolTip' + tipID).style.left       = tipLeft + 'px';
                            document.getElementById('ToolTip' + tipID).style.visibility = 'visible';
                            document.getElementById('ToolTip' + tipID).style.display    = 'block';;
                        } else {
                            stillOver = 0;
                            document.getElementById('ToolTip' + tipID).style.visibility = 'hidden';
                            document.getElementById('ToolTip' + tipID).style.display    = 'none';
                        }
                    }
                }

                function tipOver(tipID, tipDelay) {
                    stillOver = tipID;
                    setTimeout("tipShowHide(" + tipID + ", 1)", tipDelay);
                }

                function getRealLeft(el) {
                    if (arguments.length==0)
                        el = this;
                    xPos = el.offsetLeft;
                    tempEl = el.offsetParent;
                    while (tempEl != null){
                        xPos += tempEl.offsetLeft;
                        tempEl = tempEl.offsetParent;
                    }
                    return xPos;
                }

                function getRealTop(el) {
                    if (arguments.length==0)
                        el = this;
                    yPos = el.offsetTop;
                    tempEl = el.offsetParent;
                    while (tempEl != null){
                        yPos += tempEl.offsetTop;
                        tempEl = tempEl.offsetParent;
                    }
                    return yPos;
                }


            var numTips = 1;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <DIV ID="ToolTip1" style="z-index:999; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; visibility:hidden; display:none; width:685px; color:#000000; border:1px solid #000000;  background-color:#ffffee;" >
            <table style="width:200px;">
                <tr valign="top">
                    <td style="width:350px;">
                        <span style="text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold;">Test Stuff</span><br>

                        Test text
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </DIV>
        <SPAN ID="ToolTipParent1" ONMOUSEOVER="tipOver(1, 1000);" ONMOUSEOUT="tipShowHide(1, 2);">
            <div id="dynaKeyDiv" align="left" class="tableControlHeaderDiv" style="width:#tableWidth#px;">
                <table id="dynaKeyTable" border="1" class="tableControlHeader" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="width:#tableWidth#px;">
                    <tr>

                        <td style="width:100%; font-weight:bold;">
                            Test Element
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </SPAN> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The web developer's mantra: "If it works in IE, but not the other browsers, your code is wrong." Quirks mode is a different box layout compared to standards mode and you cannot expect any browser to render the markup the same.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily disagree with that mantra.  Perhaps I should restate the question: "What about my code is wrong?"  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's invalid to have a `div` inside a `span`. You should use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check for those kinds of errors.

If you use a `div` for the `ToolTipParent1` element, your problem goes away.

Comment: Wow; incredible.  Thank you :).  I had thought the only difference between divs and spans were that one was a block element and the other could be used inline.  As this is part of a generic script (the developer/user provides all content within ToolTipParent1 and could use any number of tags), is there another inline element like span that would be appropriate to use here?  Or can a div be styled to work inline?

Comment: Just to address your other comment; I would like to use a validator but the ones I know of are all online.  This website is inaccessible from the outside world and the code/data is proprietary and cannot be shared.  So I will need to wait until i can research further and find a local validator.

Comment: @Nicholas Bostaph - `div`s are invalid inside any inline element. It's possible to style a div as inline but you will probably hit the same problem if you do. I believe it's possible to download, compile and run a local copy of [validator.nu](http://about.validator.nu/#src) if you're that paranoid about the proprietary nature of your code, though I've never tried it.

Comment: "if you're that paranoid about the proprietary nature of your code" - I'm not, but I am paranoid about getting in trouble for it ;).  Thanks.